# How could we pass FileReader's result to parent's state in React?

Tags: reactjs, url

Hello and thank you for your time.

I am currently learning React.

I am trying to refactor a component to separate and put the state into a top level component, called App, and make the ImageUpload, which renders a file input and a canvas, a stateless component.

The code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

class ImageUpload extends React.Component {


    _handleImageChange(e) {
        console.log("Enter");
        e.preventDefault();

        let reader = new FileReader();
        let newFile = e.target.files[0];
        console.log("File event: " + newFile);
        this.props.onChange(newFile, reader);
        console.log("File event after: " + newFile);

        reader.readAsDataURL(newFile)
    }

    render() {
        let imagePreviewUrl = this.props.upload;
        console.log("URL IS: " + imagePreviewUrl);
        let $imagePreview = null;
        if (imagePreviewUrl) {
            $imagePreview = (<img src={imagePreviewUrl}/>);
        } else {
            $imagePreview = (
                <div className="previewText">Por favor seleccione una imagen de su ordenador para visualizarla</div>);
        }

        return (
            <div className="previewComponent">
                <form>
                    <input className="fileInput"
                           type="file"
                           onChange={(e) => this._handleImageChange(e)}/>
                </form>
                <div className="imgPreview">
                    {$imagePreview}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
    state = {file: '', upload: ''};

    setFileFromUrl = (newFile, reader) => {
        console.log("The image file in APP method is: " + newFile);
        console.log("reader is:  " + reader);
        this.setState({
            file: newFile,
            upload: reader.result
        })
        ;
        console.log("Changed image file " + (this.state.file));
        console.log("Changed READER TO " + this.state.upload);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ImageUpload onChange={this.setFileFromUrl} file={this.state.file} upload={this.state.upload}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("mainApp"));
registerServiceWorker();
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Suba una imagen desde el ordenador, para mostrarla:</h3>
<div id="mainApp"></div>
```

The code is based on: https://codepen.io/hartzis/pen/VvNGZP

I have studied the official tutorial and this course: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/react-js-getting-started/table-of-contents

The difficult I am facing is that I would like to be able to update App's state from ImageUpload child component. Currently I am able to update App's state's file. However, I do not know how to do the same with App's state's upload condition, which tells canvas whether to show a string asking for inputting and image or to show it.

Output:
First when we load the page the state is:

```
State
file:
""
upload:
""
```

Then when we upload the image:

```
State
file:
File{…}
upload:
null
```

**Why is upload null?**

Also log result is:

```
index.js:10 Enter
index.js:15 File event: [object File]
index.js:52 The image file in APP method is: [object File]
index.js:53 reader is:  [object FileReader]
index.js:59 Changed image file 
index.js:60 Changed READER TO 
index.js:17 File event after: [object File]
index.js:24 URL IS: null
```

So we see that File flows from ImageUpload to App's state through setFileFromUrl method, when an onChange is present in the ImageUpload.

***Why is URL null?***

We know that FileReader is present in setFileFromUrl, and it is supposed that we update App's state's upload in:

```
upload: reader.result
```

Also, with the Development Tools, I have tried to manually change it to true:

And the output in the canvas is that it tries to show something, but it only shows a default thumbnail:
[image]

***Could you help me please, thank you!!!***

Comment: Any luck yet at about this issue? I'm having a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use `reader.onloadend`, add it to wrap your `onChange` call :

```
_handleImageChange(e) {
    console.log("Enter");
    e.preventDefault();
    let reader = new FileReader();
    let newFile = e.target.files[0];
    reader.onloadend = () => {
        this.props.onChange(newFile, reader);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(newFile)
}
```

Working codepen : https://codepen.io/Dyo/pen/LQxEYQ?editors=0110

Also, don't log `this.state` just after `setState` it won't log updated values because `setState` is async.

Answer (score 0):

With the react function component, one could also use the below solution

```js
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import {Buffer} from 'buffer';


function FileUpload() {

  const [filedata,setFiledata] = useState({fileBuffer:'No file uploaded'});

  const uploadFile = async (event) =>{
    console.log(filedata);
    event.preventDefault();
    
    //getting file from user
    const fileName = event.target.files[0];
    console.log('You uploaded => ',fileName.name);
    const fileReader = new window.FileReader();
    //reading filecontent as buffer
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileName);
    console.log(fileReader);
    
    fileReader.onloadend = () =>{
      console.log('fileRead check in progress...');
      // console.log(Buffer(fileReader.result));
      setFiledata({fileBuffer: Buffer(fileReader.result)});
      console.log('buffer is',Buffer(fileReader.result));
    }
    
  }
  
  const fileSubmit = (event) =>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('File submitted');
    console.log('filedata is',filedata.fileBuffer);
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="FileUpload">
    
      <form onSubmit={fileSubmit}>
        <input type="file" onChange={uploadFile}></input> {/*onChange */}
        {/* {filedata.fileBuffer} */}
        <input type='submit' ></input> {/*onSubmit */}
      </form>
        
        
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default FileUpload;
```

below solution using native Node.js modules